# create dotted line chart in primefaces 5.1

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, xhtml, jqplot

I'm using Prime faces 5.1 and JSF, I want to create line chart. The line chart having multiple values.
For Example: I've line chart with 10 data points, I want to create single Line chart like 1-7 data points in line chart and 8-10 in dotted line chart.
Is this possible to achieve this in prime faces?

If possible means how can I achieve?

Comment: OR else how to generate full dotted line?

Comment: Personnaly i use http://www.highcharts.com/ for all of my chart in jsf. More easily to customize than PF chart.